# Use Django admin modules inside own forms

Tags: django, admin

In the Django admin i have a customized changelist with added search and filters. I have been looking alot but cannot seem to find a way to use the whole "changelist module" outside of admin. So i can embed it in one of my own pages.

I do not need any of the authentication or anything like that. I just want to show a table (for a content management backend) that has the nice search, sort and filter capabilities.

Is there perhaps any documentation about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use the `ChangeList` class for your own projects. I cannot give you a full documentation on doing so here, but some points to start with.

- Have a look [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L972) to see how the
  `ChangeList` has to be initialized in
  your view. (The `ChangeList` class
  lives at
  `django.contrib.admin.views.main`, so
  import it from there!)
- Look at the [admin templates](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list_results.html) to see how the
  corresponding template tags are used.
  (also [this template](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html))

Maybe you will also find the [`django.contrib.databrowse`-application](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/databrowse/) helpful!